# 選挙が行われているようです。これは何がどういう仕組みで行われているのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案, 選挙

サイトを見ていると、モデレーター選挙が行われているという掲示がありました。

この選挙というのはどういうもので、立候補したり投票したりするにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

[image: 選挙のお知らせ]

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ここでいう「選挙」とは、このサイトのコミュニティにおける[モデレーター](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)の選挙です。モデレーターとは「スタック・オーバーフロー」のモデレーションの一端を担っているユーザーです。

Stack Exchange のすべてのサイトにおいて、必要に応じて選挙が開かれます。選挙は Stack Exchange のコミュニティチームによって主導され、サイトの状況に応じて、規模の大きいサイトでは完全版の選挙が、beta サイトや小さいサイト、正式版になって間もないサイトなどでは暫定版の選挙が行われます。モデレーターを何人選ぶのかや、どちらのタイプの選挙を行うのかは、選挙の最初にアナウンスされます。

さて、選挙では、4 つの段階を通してモデレーターを選出します：

### 段階 0: アナウンス、そして質問の募集

#### 期間: 7 日間

まずコミュニティ・チームによってメタに選挙のアナウンスが投稿されます。

同時に、それぞれの候補者に答えてほしい質問の候補をコミュニティから募集します。（コミュニティからの要望が無い限り、これは普通完全版の選挙でのみ行われ、暫定版の選挙では行われません。）

### 段階 1: 立候補

#### 期間: 7 日間

一定の条件を満たしていれば、誰でもモデレーターとして立候補できます。

- 「スタック・オーバーフロー」において一定以上の信用度を獲得していること。この閾値はふつう 300 です。一部のサイトにおいて例外がありますが、それは特殊な状況があるときに限られ、普通は変更されません。
- サイト上での振る舞いが良いこと。すべての候補者は、Stack Exchange ネットワーク上のいずれのサイトにおいても、[この過去 1 年の間アカウントを停止されていない](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year)必要があります。ただしアカウント停止が何らかの不手際であった場合はこの限りではありません。
- [18 歳以上であること](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357378/355458)。候補者は選挙が終わる時点で 18 歳以上である必要があります。

また英語版 Stack Overflow では特定のバッジを持っていることも条件になりますが、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにこの条件はありません。

立候補されたとしても参加は強制されません。任意の段階において辞退できます。

立候補は新しいものから順に表示され、最初の方に立候補された候補者がページの下の方に表示されます。

候補者は、短い自己紹介と共に自分がモデレーターにふさわしい理由を書くことになります。任意のユーザーはそれぞれの候補者の自己紹介に[コメント](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)できます。

[image: 候補者]

サイトによっては、前の段階で質問リストが作られています。これは Stack Exchange チームによって編纂され、2 つの標準的な質問とコミュニティから提案された質問の中からトップ 8 を加え、全部で 10 個の質問になります。もしコミュニティからの質問が足りない場合、標準的な質問が最大 3 個まで追加されます。候補者はこれらの質問に答えることが推奨されます。もし答えた場合、その回答が立候補の掲示とリンクされます。

（この仕組みは、昔の選挙ではメタでの投稿として行われていました。今は選挙用のシステムで行われています。）

7 日後、信用度順にトップ 30 人の候補者が「予備選」の段階に進みます。もし候補者が 10 人以下で、かつ募集されているモデレーターの人数より多かった場合、予備選はスキップされ、直接「選挙」の段階に進みます。

もし候補者が少なかった場合、選挙の種類が完全版なのか暫定版なのかによって起こることが変わります：

- 完全版の選挙では、候補者の数が募集されている人数以下だった場合、立候補の段階が 7 日間延長されます。その上でも足りなかった場合、選挙自体がすべてキャンセルされます。
- 暫定版の選挙では、最終的に候補者が一切いなかった場合、期限が 7 日間延長されます。その上で候補者が現れなかった場合、選挙がキャンセルされます。候補者は居るが募集されている人数以下だった場合、立候補の段階が終わった時点でその候補者たちがそのまま当選したことになり、それ以降の段階は執り行われません。

### 段階 2: 予備選

#### 期間: 4 日間

この段階はもし 10 人より多い候補者が集まった場合に行われます。10 人以下だった場合、この段階はスキップされ、直接「選挙」の段階に進みます。

この段階から、投票が始まります。コミュニティの任意のメンバーは、信用度を最低 150 持っていれば投票ができます（※）。ただし[候補者が自分自身に投票することはできません](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170909)。それぞれの候補者ごとに、通常の質問や回答に投票するのと同様に 1 票投票が可能です。コメントはできません。

投票は、コメントの横に表示されている上下の矢印を使って行います。上向き矢印によるプラス投票は「この候補者が次の段階に進んで欲しい」ということを表し、下向き矢印によるマイナス投票は進んで欲しくないということを表します。

[image: 予備選]

この時点においても、候補者は参加を強制されておらず、任意のタイミングで参加を辞退できます。また候補者はランダムな順番で表示されます。

投票の様子は公表されます。したがって誰が当選しそうかの様子を伺うことができます。ただし、もし候補者が合計でマイナスの票になっている場合、票数は 0 と表示されます。あるいはあなたが投票した後には 1 か -1 と表示されます。投票するのに充分な信用度を持っている場合（※）、通常の投稿と同じく、数字をクリックすることで実際の投票数を見ることができます。

4 日経ったあと、票の合計値が多かったトップ 10 人の候補者が「選挙」の段階に進みます。

### 段階 3: 選挙

#### 期間: 4 日間（予備選がスキップされた場合、8 日間）

最後の段階が「選挙」の段階です。信用度 150 以上のユーザーは投票できます。予備選と異なり、[候補者は自分自身にも投票できます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170909)。予備選と同じく、コメントはできず、候補者はランダムな順番で表示されます。

それぞれのコミュニティ・メンバーはひとつの投票権を持ち、候補者を順番に並べる形で投票できます。得票数は[ミーク法 (Meek STV 法)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)  によって計算されます。これがどのような仕組みかは[この動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P38Y4VG1Ibo)をご覧ください。それぞれの投票者は、最も好ましい候補者を選ぶと共に、その次に好ましい候補者を順番に選ぶことができます。もし投票者の最も上の候補者が当選してしかもある閾値以上の投票を得ていた場合に、追加で選択していた票が部分的な投票として数えられます。

（昔の選挙では候補者の中からトップ 3 人を選んで投票する方式でしたが、この方式は変更され、候補者全員を選んで並べることができるようになりました。）

[image: 選挙の段階での投票 UI。ドラッグアンドドロップで選べます]

なお、予備選と異なり、投票の様子は隠されます。

### その他の情報

暫定版の選挙に当選した人は、そのサイトで最初に開かれた完全版の選挙において、立候補して再び当選することもできれば、選挙が終わり次第モデレーターを辞することもできます。

Meta Stack Exchange のユーザー [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode) によって、さまざまなサイトの選挙の様子を見ることができるサイトが作られています: https://artofcode.co.uk/elections。このサイトは元々 [Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313758/yi-jiang) によって作られ Stack Exchange でホストされていましたが、HTTPS 関係の事情でクローズし、今の形になりました。

過去の選挙のページは記録のために残され、`/election` で確認することができます。スタック・オーバーフローの選挙の記録はこちらです: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election。

何らかの選挙が進行中の場合、過去の結果は部分的に隠され、`/election/<選挙の番号>` で閲覧できます。選挙が起こっていなければ、過去の選挙の結果が全て `/election` で確認できます。

---

※ 投票可能かどうか判断するためにチェックされるのは信用度のみです。モデレーターになる権利があるものの信用度が足りない場合は投票できません。また、予備選において投票数の内訳を見ることもできません。

スタック・オーバーフローの現在のモデレーターの一覧は https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators で確認できます。また、Stack Exchange のサイトたちにおけるモデレーターの一覧は [Stack Exchange のページ](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)で確認でき、その他の情報は[ブログ](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/moderators/)でも確認できます。

---

この Q&A は [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/341401) を元に日本語で書いたものです。