# ベータ版の卒業に伴い、最初の選挙を行います！

Tags: 討議, 選挙

**要約**：スタック・オーバーフローはベータ版を卒業し、正式版になりました。これに伴い、2022 年 3 月 15 日 (JST) から[モデレーター選挙](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1)の立候補を募り始めます。

今後の予定：

- 3 月 8 日、 立候補者への質問をコミュニティから募るための投稿が、@JNat さんよりメタへ投稿されます。
- 3 月 15 日より、[立候補](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1)ができるようになります。ひとつ前の週に集められた質問たちの中から上位のものが編纂され質問リストとなり、モデレーター候補者の皆さんが答えられるように提示されます。
- 既存のモデレーターの皆さんは、そのままモデレーターであり続けるためには立候補する必要があります。
- 3 月 22 日、もし 4 名以上の立候補者がいれば、実際の選挙が始まります。もしそうでなければ、立候補の期間が 1 週間延長されます。それでも立候補が 4 名集まらなかった場合、選挙はキャンセルされ、コミュニティとモデレーターチームとで選挙期間の再設定を行います。（また、場合によっては[立候補を取り消す](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/341401)こともありますが、ほぼ起こることは無いでしょう。）
- 選挙が完了した場合、3 月 30 日（立候補が延長された場合は 4 月 6 日）、@JNat さんによってメタに結果が投稿されます。

もし何か選挙の進め方について質問があれば、この投稿に回答として投稿してください。

<sub>（この投稿は @JNat さんによる投稿依頼を受け @nekketsuuu が日本語に翻訳し代理で投稿しています。）</sub>

Comment: MSE に投稿されていた FAQ を元に日本語で FAQ を書いたものはこちら: [選挙が行われているようです。これは何がどういう仕組みで行われているのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3695/19110)

Answer (score 3):

質問です。自己紹介や質問への回答などで立候補者が何か書く場合、それらはすべて日本語であるべきですか？　つまり、英語など他の言語で書く場合は日本語訳を同時に書いておくべきでしょうか。

個人的には、日本語で自己紹介などが行われるべきだと考えています。スタック・オーバーフローは日本語でモデレーションが行われているサイトであるからです。仮に最初は英語で書いたとしても、日本語での説明も載せた方が、コミュニティのためになるでしょう。投票者が立候補者の情報を正確に知るという意味でも日本語の情報が必要とされているように思います。

参考までに、スタック・オーバーフローでは今のところ質問は日本語併記が好まれ ([1](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/19110)、[2](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1815/19110))、回答は英語も許容しつつ日本語併記も考える ([3](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1990/19110)) ということになっています。

Comment: 立候補者への質問や紹介、実際の回答は全て日本語で大丈夫です。Stack Overflow 多言語サイト（ポルトガル語、ロシア語、スペイン語）でも同じことが言えると思います。結局のところはみなさんご存知のように本サイトスタック・オーバーフローは日本語を話す人のための場所です。また、通常は CM チームの対応が必要であるモデレーションサポートについては aki が常駐しています。質問ありがとうございます！

Comment: @JNat 微妙にニュアンスが伝わっていないかもしれません。日本語が OK なのはもちろんとして、「英語のみ」が NG かどうかを確認しておきたいです。

Comment: 本サイトのすべてのUIと（すべてではない時もあるのかもしれませんが）ほとんどのユーザー間でのやり取りが日本語で行われていること、そして日本語コミュニティ向けに諸々が調整されていることを考慮すると、全て日本語であることが理にかなっています。当選モデレーターは日本語に堪能である必要があります。でなければ本サイトのコンテンツをモデレートする能力が大幅に妨げられてしまうからです。そのことを念頭に、有権者も日本語に堪能である可能性が高いという事実とともに、「英語のみ」での立候補者の自己紹介には意味がないと思います。- 許可しないとまでは明言しませんが、英語のみのものにはメリットがありません。

Comment: 明言ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

段階 1 の候補者の推薦には、誰でも自身をモデレーターとして自薦できる、と書かれていますが<sup>[[1]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3696/32986)</sup>、この段階で行えるのは自薦のみという認識でよいでしょうか？推薦というと自薦だけでなく他薦も含みそうだと感じたので気になりました。

> ### 段階 1: 候補者の推薦<sup>[[1]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3696/32986)</sup>
>
> #### 期間: 7 日間
>
> 一定の条件を満たしていれば、誰でも自身をモデレーターとして自薦できます。

Comment: 他薦は含まれません。スタック・オーバーフローの選挙制度では、自己推薦のみが認められています。

Comment: @supa ご質問ありがとうございます！自薦のみですよと明確にするため、1) FAQ 案の箇所を「段階 1: 候補者の推薦」 ->「段階 1: 立候補」それから、2) 選挙ページの箇所を 「候補者推薦の段階」 -> 「立候補の段階」と変更させていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @aki さん> コメントありがとうございます！私もそのほうが明確になって良いと思います。